# EPPLUS CreateArrayFormula is wrapped in curly brackets using FILTER and SORT functions

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have the following code:

`for (var x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
   var prepCell = orderSheet.Cells[$"{ExcelColumnFromNumber(x + 26)}1"];
   prepCell.CreateArrayFormula($"_xlfn._xlws.SORT(_xlfn.UNIQUE(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER('Wearers'!A2:A1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B{x},'Wearers'!A2:A1000)))));
}`

When I open up the Excel result, I get the following in the cell:

`{=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Wearers!A2:A1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B5,Wearers!A2:A1000)))))}`

I am referencing this cell from a dropdown using the dynamic array spill character (#) but I have to click on the formula and press enter to get it to remove the curly brackets. Is there a way that it can just work, without having to click on each cell?

Comment: Maybe just remove those characters from the formula? `prepCell.Formula = cell.Formula.Replace("{","").Replace("}", "");`. There's probably a smart regex for this but I'm not an expert at it.

Comment: The problem is the curly brackets only appear once opened in Excel, not within the generation of the file.